# Number of Post Views is not showing in template ( Function Based Views )

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I am Building a BlogApp and I implement a feature to count the views of Post. BUT views are not showing in post page in Browser.

**What i am trying to do**

I am trying to count the number of views which post will got whenever the user visits.

**The Problem**

Post views are not showing in post page in browser.

**What have i tried**

1).  I also tried `models.IntegerField` BUT that didn't worked for me , because whenever user refresh the page then it increase one view everytime for single user.

2).  I followed some tutorials BUT the all of them were on `Class Based Views` and I am using `Function Based Views`.

3).  Then i thought of `IP address` BUT that also didn't worked for me because it wasn't working for my server.

*Then i think of a `ManyToManyField` in `views` variable*. BUT it also not working for me, I don't know where is the problem.

views.py

```
def detail_view(request,pk):
    data = get_object_or_404(BlogPost,pk=pk)
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.order_by('viewers')
    context = {'queryset':queryset,'data':data}
    return render(request, 'mains/show_more.html', context )
```

models.py

```
class BloPost(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    date_added = models
    viewers = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='viewed_posts',editable=False)
```

show_more.html

1). This is showing `auth.User.None`

```
{{ data.viewers }}
```

2). This is showing all the posts.

```
{{ queryset }}
```

I don't what am i doing wrong.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: `{{ data.viewers.count }}` will give you the count of the related instances.

Comment: Thanks for comment. BUT It is showing `0` all the time.

Comment: @Progam: of course, you never add any users to the `viewers`. Exactly why do you want to use a FBV?

Comment: I want it to automatic count the views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should annotate your queryset, so:

```
from django.db.models import Count

def detail_view(request,pk):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.annotate(
        num_views=Count('viewers')
    ).order_by('-num_views')
    data = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
    context = {'queryset':queryset,'data':data}
    return render(request, 'mains/show_more.html', context )
```

and then you can render this with:

```
{{ data.num_views }}
```

If you want to add the user to the viewers, you can run the logic to add the user to the viewers:

```
from django.db.models import Count

def detail_view(request,pk):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.annotate(
        num_views=Count('viewers')
    ).order_by('-num_views')
    data = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
    if self.user.is_authenticated:
        __, created = Post.viewers.through.objects.get_or_create(
            post=data,
            user=self.request.user
        )
        if created:
            data.num_views += 1
    context = {'queryset':queryset,'data':data}
    return render(request, 'mains/show_more.html', context )
```

That being said, this to some extent demonstrates that function-based views are often not well-suited for a view that requires to run logic that consists out of a number of separate parts. In that case it is better to work with *mixins* and define a class-based view in terms of these mixins.

Comment: Add the User to the BlogPosts's viewers. I think the OP is not doing that.

Comment: @Progam: yes, it is `num_views`, not `num_view`.

Comment: I also did that `num_views`

Comment: @Progam: no, what I mean is that there was a typo in the template part...

Comment: Ok Ok I understand

Comment: I understand BUT it will be little difficult to exchange `FBV` into `CBV`

Comment: @Progam: with the current view, I think that is definitely doable.

Comment: The code you gave is working BUT it always showing `2` views.

Comment: @Progam if you find it difficult to change to CBV try to begin by using only the generic `View` and later you will find yourself learning how to use the others.

Comment: @Progam: well you count the number of distinct users, so refreshing will not increase the count. You can `print(data.viewers.all())` to find out who has viewed your `Post`.

Comment: It's working correctly BUT it adds `2` view who created the blogpost. AND it is counting 1 - 1 for every new user. I mean it is working correctly for new users BUT adding 2 views for user who created it